# Polymorphic pattern matching results in ambiguous type

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, pattern-matching

(Inspired by [cannot match on polymorphic tuples with constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137421/cannot-match-on-polymorphic-tuples-with-constraints), and based on a subsequent [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137421/cannot-match-on-polymorphic-tuples-with-constraints#comment100805403_57138105) on my own answer.)

Consider the following minimal example:

```hs
test :: (Show a, Show b) => (a -> String, b -> String)
test = (show,show)

(resX, resY) = test
```

This results in the following error:

```
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘test’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        resX :: a0 -> String (bound at so.hs:25:2)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus 17 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: test
      In a pattern binding: (resX, resY) = test
   |
25 | (resX, resY) = test
   |                ^^^^
```

This makes sense: that pattern match doesn’t constrain `a` or `b` in any way, so they’re ambiguous. But how do I get rid of this error? Just about every attempt to solve this by adding type signature(s) gives another error. For instance:

```hs
-- attempt 1
test :: (Show a, Show b) => (a -> String, b -> String)
test = (show,show)

resX :: Show a => a -> String
resY :: Show b => b -> String
(resX, resY) = test

-- attempt 2
test :: (Show a, Show b) => (a -> String, b -> String)
test = (show,show)

(resX, resY) = test :: (Show a, Show b) => (a -> String, b -> String)
```

So: how can I get rid of the ambiguity error? And why do the above attempts fail?

Comment: The problem is that when you define `resX`, it thus means that it is equivalent to `fst test`. `test` has signature `(Show a, Show b) => (a -> String, b -> String)`, so the question is: what to do with `b`? That is ambiguous. This is one of the reasons not to use tuples for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This makes sense: that pattern match doesn’t constrain a or b in any way, so they’re ambiguous. But how do I get rid of this error?

Giving type signatures will not help here. The type for `test` is `(Show a, Show b) => (a -> String, b -> String)`. Basically what you do is write:

```
resX :: Show a => a -> String
resX = fst test
```

The question is however, what should Haskell fill in for `b` from the signature of `test`? You might say that this does not matter, and here it indeed does not matter. But if you defined `test` through a typeclass for example. The `a` and `b` type could determine *together* what the implementation for the first item would be. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class (Show a, Show b) => SomeTest a b where
    test :: (a -> String, b -> String)

instance SomeTest Bool Bool where
    test = (const "foo", const "bar")

instance SomeTest Bool Int where
    test = (const "qux", const "bar")
```

here the second type parameter determines the implementation of the first item of `test`, and hence we can not just omit that.

You can for example use the `TypeApplications` extension, to provide a type for the other type parameter (here `Bool`):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications -#}

test :: (Show a, Show b) => (a -> String, b -> String)
test = (show, show)

resX :: Show a => a -> String
resX = fst (test @_ @Bool)

resY :: Show a => a -> String
resY = snd (test @Bool)
```

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer! I have a further question: is there a way to get both `resX` and `resY` in the same declaration? Presumably `(resX, resY) = (fst (test @_ @Bool), snd (test @Bool))` works, but is there any easier way?

Comment: @bradrn: not as far as I know no, since if you would "combine" the two, then that means that `a` still can depend on `b` and vice versa.

Answer (score 6):

It's instructive to think about how your code actually works at runtime. Type classes have *dictionary passing* semantics. Classy code

```
class Foo a where
    foo :: a -> Int

instance Foo Int where
    foo = id

useFoo :: Foo a => a -> IO ()
useFoo x = print (foo x)

callFoo = useFoo (123 :: Int)
```

is compiled into non-classy code.

```
data Foo_ a = Foo_ { foo :: a -> Int }

foo_Int :: Foo_ Int
foo_Int = Foo_ { foo = id }

useFoo :: Foo_ a -> a -> IO ()
useFoo dict x = print (foo dict x)

callFoo = useFoo foo_Int 123
```

The "fat arrow" `=>` really means exactly the same thing at runtime as the "scrawny arrow" `->`. The only difference is that `=>`'s argument is passed implicitly by the constraint solver.

So let's think about your `Show` example from this perspective. A type like `test :: (Show a, Show b) => (a -> String, b -> String)` really means `test :: (Show_ a, Show_ b) -> (a, String, b -> String)`. You can't factorise that function into a pair of functions `(Show_ a -> a -> String, Show_ b -> b -> String)`. The body of the function might make use of both `Show_` dictionaries before returning a result, so you have to supply both before you can get the `(a -> String, b -> String)` out.

When inferring a type for `resx`, the type checker will come up with `resx :: (Show a, Show b) => a -> String` — it needs both instances in scope in order to call `test`. Clearly this is an ambiguous type. `b` doesn't appear to the right of the `=>`, so at `resx`'s call site there will never be enough local type information to call it successfully.

You might object that one *should* be able to carry out such a factorisation in this case. The two halves of `test`'s body can't use each others' `Show` instances, because `Show`'s methods only talk about their type parameter as an input and the input is not in scope in the wrong half of the tuple. But that's a sophisticated argument from parametricity about runtime behaviour, and it only holds for this specific case. It's not the sort of dumb syntax-directed reasoning a compiler is good at.

Comment: “You might object that one _should_ be able to carry out such a factorisation in this case.” Question: similarly to how `(a1,a2) -> (b1,b2)` can be factored into `(a1->b1, a2->b2)`, would you be able to factor `(constr1, constr2) => (a1, a2)` into `(constr1 => a1, constr2 => a2)` (inserting rank N types as appropriate)?

Comment: `(a1, a2) -> (b1, b2)` *can’t* be factored into `(a1 -> b1, a2 -> b2)`. Try it!

Comment: Also, your `(c1 => a1, c2 => a2)` is not a valid type because it’s impredicative.

Comment: I’m aware of that fact already. I suppose I should have been more specific: in this case, I _know_ that `b1` only depends on `a1` and `b2` only depends on `a2`, so _in this specific situation_ I can rewrite the declaration to be of that different type.

Comment: And you’re correct that that would be impredicative — I just realised that now. I suppose I could use newtypes to avoid that though.

Comment: Exactly - which is why it’s not reasonable to expect a compiler to be able to make the transformation.

Comment: That does make sense @BenhaminHodgson — thanks for explaining!

Comment: Happy to help! 